Expected value of fastest career hat-trick?
This is a sports variation of line segment (rope, stick...) divided into $n+1$ subsegments by $n$ uniformly distributed points.
Assuming goals are uniformly distributed among player's career, what's the expected value of fastest hat-trick (3 goals) as measured by time between goals? (Real hat-tricks count only if they happen within single match, of course, but let's ignore this detail, it adds too much complexity to the problem).
Here is the solution for fastest brace (2 goals):
According to this answer expected value of shortest subsegment length:
$$
\mathbb{E}[shortest\_period\_without\_goals] = \frac{career\_matches\ {\small(or\ career\_minutes)}}{(career\_goals+1)^2}
$$
However, a brace can't be first or last subsegment, because there are no goals at the career beginning and end, so out of $n(n-1)$ permutations of $2$ shortest subsegments indices:
The shortest subsegment is not first or last: $(n-2)(n-1)$ permutations;
The shortest subsegment is first or last, but 2nd shortest  is not: $2(n-2)$ permutations;
The shortest and 2nd shortest subsegments are first and last: $2$ permutations.
After simplifying we finally get:
$$
\mathbb{E}[fastest\_brace\_time] = \frac{career\_matches\ {\small(or\ career\_minutes)}}{career\_goals^2-1 }
$$
But what about fastest hat-trick?
I mean, the line segment $\overline{A_0A_{n+1}}$ of length $1$ is divided to $n+1$ parts by $n$ uniformly distributed points: $\{{A_m|1\leq m \leq n, A_0\leq A_m\leq A_{m+1}\leq A_{n+1}}\}$.
Then we take $n-2$ subsegments (to avoid $A_0$ and $A_{n+1}$ which are not goals) with exactly $1$ point inside $\{{\overline{A_{m}A_{m+2}}|1\leq m \leq n-2}\}$ and choose the shortest.
What will be an expected value of its length?

Update: I wrote a small program that uses Monte Carlo methods to get some practical results. Probably they can help someone to find an analytic solution or/and verify it. Here are the expected values of $\{{\overline{A_{m}A_{m+2}}|0\leq m \leq n-1}\}$ lengths, sorted from shortest to longest:



# Points
$\mathbb{E}[1^{st}]$
$\mathbb{E}[2^{nd}]$
$\mathbb{E}[3^{rd}]$
$\mathbb{E}[4^{th}]$
$\mathbb{E}[5^{th}]$
$\mathbb{E}[6^{th}]$
$\mathbb{E}[7^{th}]$




2
$\frac{3}{6}$
$\frac{5}{6}$







3
$\frac{9}{32}$
$\frac{16}{32}$
$\frac{23}{32}$






4
$\frac{34}{180}$
$\frac{55}{180}$
$\frac{85}{180}$
$\frac{114}{180}$





5
$\frac{530}{3888}$
$\frac{850}{3888}$
$\frac{1185}{3888}$
$\frac{1708}{3888}$
$\frac{2207}{3888}$




6
$\frac{1890}{18144}$
$\frac{2977}{18144}$
$\frac{4121}{18144}$
$\frac{5355}{18144}$
$\frac{7408}{18144}$
$\frac{9352}{18144}$



7
$\frac{16937}{204800}$
$\frac{3309}{25600}$
$\frac{967759}{5529600}$
$\frac{19571}{86400}$
$\frac{1564889}{5529600}$
$\frac{52621}{138240}$
$\frac{11621}{24576}$



And here are the probabilistic estimation of expected values for shortest and longest segments (not all digits are verified):



# Points
$10$
$20$
$30$
$40$
$50$
$100$
$200$
$300$
$500$
$1000$




$\mathbb{E}[shortest]$
$\frac{1}{20.766}$
$\frac{1}{60.382}$
$\frac{1}{113.16}$
$\frac{1}{176.71}$
$\frac{1}{249.59}$
$\frac{1}{727.46}$
$\frac{1}{2107.8}$
$\frac{1}{3917.2}$
$\frac{1}{8529}$
$\frac{1}{24428}$


$\mathbb{E}[longest]$
$\small0.38163$
$\small0.23944$
$\small0.17803$
$\small0.1431$
$\small0.1203$
$\small0.0689$
$\small0.0387$
$\small0.0274$
$\small0.0176$
$\small0.0096$



It seems like $lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[shortest]$ is close to $\mathcal{O}(1/n\sqrt{n})$, and it makes sense: like in birthday problem, for most subsegment permutations at least 1 pair of $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ shortest subsegments will be adjacent and the expected length of $\sqrt{n}^{th}$ shortest subsegment is also $\mathcal{O}(1/n\sqrt{n})$.
Note: those numbers can be used to answer the initial question only if they are multiplied by ${career\_matches\ {\small(or\ career\_minutes)}\ between\_first\_and\_last\_goals}$.

What is a "hat trick"?

@XanderHenderson I added a link, but you can skip it and follow right to the definition in math terms :)

I stated (maybe after your comment) that I prefer to ignore match boundaries. It makes a mathematical problem definition much more clear and probably easier to solve (however I admit I can't solve it).
